# How to load an html webpage inside unity3d

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, webview, html

I want to show a webpage inside unity3d without making it an image and load it via a WWW class.

I have seen that there are plugins, but I would like to load the web page without one.

Answer (score 8):

1. You need a plugin because the best way to do what you want is "webview"
2. If you really don't want to use a plugin, then use `Applicaion.OpenUrl` instead. This will open web pages, but not inside the unity window. It will open a browser application and show webpage.
3. If you want to use a plugin, check this github
   https://github.com/gree/unity-webview

Comment: I've already seen  the plugin on GitHub, but I did not quite understand how it is used.

I tried to open Sample.unity and then import unity-webview.unitypackage, but I can not find the url string so that I can change it.

Comment: There is a variable ‘Url’ in samplewebview.cs file. That is public variable, so you can change it in inspector window.

Comment: If you select the SampleWebView object you will see the Url on the Inspector

Comment: Unfortunately, it is not supported on windows. Any window solution available?

Comment: It's a shame unity-webview doesn't support windows... It could be an epic enterprise-level solution but it's missing basic OS support :(

Answer (score 2):

I recently did a deep dive into this, and apparently it's not possible without some sort of plugin. I tried some open source libraries, but they could only show a 2D webview on top of the app. So, I ended up going with [this 3D webview asset](https://developer.vuplex.com), since it works inside of the scene.